# Join multiple consecutive SQLite database dump files into 1 common database? Purpose: Search through ENTIRE Chrome Browsing History

Tags: google-chrome, sqlite

**Google Chrome** 's default **web browsing history search engine** only lets you access the records of the recent 100 days.
Nevertheless in your application data, Chrome keeps your **entire** browsing history in SQLite database files, with the file naming scheme of "History Index YYYY-MM".

I am looking for a way **to search…**

1. …through my **entire browsing history**,
2. …with **sophisticated filters** (limit search terms to certain fields such as URL, domain, title, body text; wildcard or regex terms, date ranges).

… in …

1. …either some **ready-made software**.

   - [eHistory](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hiiknjobjfknoghbeelhfilaaikffopb) came close, as it can limit terms to fields, but it lacks wildcards/regexes, and has the same limited time horizon as the default search.
   - Beyond that, I could not find any suited Chrome extension or standalone (Mac) app.
2. …or a **command line** to join multiple SQLite database files into one database, which I can then query (with the full syntax power). In the spirit of the pseudo code below:

   - Preferred this way: `sqlite --targetDatabase ChromeHistoryAll --importFiles /path/to/ChromeAppData/History\ Index* --importOnlyYetUnknownFiles`
   - Or if my desired feature --importOnlyYetUnknownFiles is not possible (feature could also be called "avoid duplicate imports by checking UIDs"), then by explicitly only importing files, of which I know, that they have yet not been imported into the ChromeHistoryAll database: `cd ChromeAppData; sqlite --databaseTarget ChromeHistoryAll --importFiles YetNotImported1 YetNotImported2 YetNotImported3`
   - All my queries I would then perform in the database "ChromeHistoryAll"

*P.S.: Additional question of general interest:* Is there a way to perform a database query in a temporary database which was created on-the-fly from multiple files?

Like: `sqlite --query="SQL query" --targetDatabase DbAll --DBtemporaryInRAM --importFiles db1 db2 db3`

This is surely not applicable for my Chrome question, as these History Index files have a combined file size of 500MB together, thus such a query would be of bad performance. But it could come handy in other situations.